# Covering the plane with compact sets, II

Tags: general-topology, geometry, tiling

A previous question [Covering the plane with compact sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436714/covering-the-plane-with-compact-sets) received a (to me) unexpected, simple, and elegant solution, which, moreover, possessed the merit of continuity. This time the constraints are more demanding.

The problem is to find two partitions of the plane into closed sets, related to each other as follows. The first partition consists of pairwise disjoint closed sets $V_{\alpha}$ all of which except one, $V_0$,  are compact. The second partition likewise consists of pairwise disjoint closed sets $W_{\beta}$ all of which except one, $W_0$,  are compact. The partitions are related thus:

(1) $V_0$ and $W_0$ are disjoint;

(2) each $V_{\alpha}$ (except $V_0$) meets each $W_{\beta}$ (except $W_0$) in exactly a singleton;

(3) each $V_{\alpha}$ meets $W_0$ in at most a singleton, and each $W_{\beta}$ meets $V_0$ in at most a singleton.

Can two such partitions be found?

Comment: In (2) do you really want every $V_\alpha$ to meet every $W_\beta$ in exactly a singleton? (Or in at most a singleton?)

Comment: In exactly a singleton. The constraints come from a C*-algebra construction.

Comment: doesn't this condition force $W_0$ and $V_0$ to have bounded complement then?

Comment: Why? I don't see this just now.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: I wondered that too at first, and certainly $V_0$ and $W_0$ are the only unbounded sets in their respective partitions. But one could conceive of a situation where the collection of bounded $V_\alpha$'s (and the bounded $W_\beta$'s) accumulate at infinity.

Comment: If the $V_0$ and $W_0$ are both unbounded then they cannot have bounded complements. They induce a separation unto disjoint closed sets of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus B$ for some open ball $B$, which is of course not possible. This raises the  question, are they required to be non-compact or just allowed to be?

Comment: @DavidHartley Because of the C*-algebra context there are also continuity constraints which I hadn't really thought about when I posed the question. They imply that "at most" in condition (3) should be "exactly" and that $V_0$ and $W_0$ are both non-compact. I am afraid I don't follow your argument, though.

Comment: My comment was a bit mangled. I meant to say, *if* $V_0$ and $W_0$ were both unbounded and with bounded complements *then* they would induce a separation of the complement of some ball $B$, which is not possible as it is connected. ($B$ being chosen large enough to contain the bounded complements.) A simpler argument would be, each is contained in the complement of the other, so if they are both unbounded then so are their complements