# Partitioning the 2-sphere into compact homeomorphic subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

This question is related to a previous one [Covering the plane with compact sets, II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438661/covering-the-plane-with-compact-sets-ii) (as yet unanswered).

Can the 2-sphere be partitioned into an infinite family of disjoint compact subsets, all of which are homeomorphic to each other and of the same cardinality as the continuum?

Comment: Yes, it can be partitioned into Cantor sets. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4162677/partitioning-a-metric-space-into-cantor-sets

Comment: @DavidHartley Many thanks. I have posted a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442042/can-the-quotient-space-obtained-by-partitioning-the-closed-interval-into-cantor